# Removing "NA" from a substring in R

Tags: r, substring

Below shows an example of the dataframe I have. Please note that I have many other columns in my dataframe and my data type is "character" for the given column.

```
Time 
NA, 2017-07-24 04:13:00
2017-07-24 07:01:12
NA, 2017-07-24 05:18:00
2017-07-24 05:00:45, NA
NA, 2017-07-24 19:44:30, NA
```

I wish to remove all "NA", commas and spaces (spaces inbetween "NA" and times). Thus the result I require is as follows.

```
Time 
2017-07-24 04:13:00
2017-07-24 07:01:12
2017-07-24 05:18:00
2017-07-24 05:00:45
2017-07-24 19:44:30
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
your_data$better_time = gsub(
  pattern = "NA, |, NA",
  replacement = "",
  x = your_data$Time)
```

The `pattern = "NA, |, NA"` is a regular expression that will match either `NA,` or `, NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `str_extract` from `stringr`. This extracts what's needed instead of removing what's not:

```
library(stringr)

df = df %>%
  mutate(Time = str_extract(Time, "\\d.+\\d"))
```

**Notes:**

- `\\d` matches a digit
- `.+` matches any character one or more times. This matching is greedy, meaning that it will search for the longest string that matches the pattern
- `\\d.+\\d` matches a digit followed by any character one or more times and a digit.

**Result:**

```
                 Time
1 2017-07-24 04:13:00
2 2017-07-24 07:01:12
3 2017-07-24 05:18:00
4 2017-07-24 05:00:45
5 2017-07-24 19:44:30
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Time = c("NA, 2017-07-24 04:13:00", "2017-07-24 07:01:12", 
"NA, 2017-07-24 05:18:00", "2017-07-24 05:00:45, NA", "NA, 2017-07-24 19:44:30, NA"
)), .Names = "Time", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```